# Stationary video camera calibration without pattern

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Sometimes it is necessary to perform video camera calibration without access to the physical camera or camera parameters. In this case it is also unlikely that the images will contain a calibration pattern and additionally all images may be taken from a fixed position. This means camera calibration techniques based on calibration patterns or feature matching/structure from motion cannot be applied.

How can camera calibration be achieved, or at least approximated, in this case?

Comment: what is it you want to calibrate? in general it is not possible to calibrate a camera without known features in the images

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear, I'm talking about removing lens distortion. A straight line photographed with a fish eye lens will turn into a curved line due to radial distortion. By calibration I mean determining the distortion parameters necessary to remove the distortion such that straight lines are straight.